# Multiple file upload asp.net and save filename in database

Tags: asp.net

I have a jquery multiple file uploader.
It uses ajax code to upload file using File handler
This is the uploader code:

```
  var selectedFiles;

  $(document).ready(function () {

    if (!Modernizr.draganddrop) {
      alert("This browser doesn't support File API and Drag & Drop features of HTML5!");
      return;
    }

    var box;
    box = document.getElementById("box");
    box.addEventListener("dragenter", OnDragEnter, false);
    box.addEventListener("dragover", OnDragOver, false);
    box.addEventListener("drop", OnDrop, false);

    $("#upload").click(function () {
      var data = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        data.append(selectedFiles[i].name, selectedFiles[i]);
      }
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FileHandler.ashx",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
          alert(result);
        },
        error: function () {
          alert("There was error uploading files!");
        }
      });
    });

  });

  function OnDragEnter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function OnDragOver(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function OnDrop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    selectedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;
    $("#box").text(selectedFiles.length + " file(s) selected for uploading!");
  }


</script>
```

This is the c# sharp code in Filehander.ashx

```
public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            foreach (string key in files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[key];
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                fileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + fileName);
                file.SaveAs(fileName);
            }
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("File(s) uploaded successfully!");
    }
```

But I want these filenames on my main page when I click the Asp.net button.
How can I get the filenames back?

Comment: "I want these filenames on my main page when I click the Asp.net button" what does that even mean? Have you tried anything, mayhaps?

Comment: <input id="upload" type="button" value="Upload Selected Files" />

Comment: This is the html button ..When user click the button this ajax code call the filehandler code to upload file    
    $("#upload").click(function () {
      var data = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        data.append(selectedFiles[i].name, selectedFiles[i]);
      }
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FileHandler.ashx",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
          alert(result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a data class like below;

```
public class FileDataModel
{
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

And your handler like below, maybe you can check other null states or is file exists etc;

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
                using (FileDbContext ctx = new FileDbContext())
                {
                    foreach (string key in files)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            HttpPostedFile file = files[key];
                            string fileName = file.FileName;
                            fileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + fileName);
                            file.SaveAs(fileName);
                            ctx.Files.Add(new FileDataModel()
                            {
                                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                FileName = file.FileName,
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid()
                            })
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }

                    }
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("File(s) uploaded successfully!");
        }
```